# How to change a name of multiple data frames in R by adding the same phrase "_movie1" to it?

Tags: r, dataframe

my first post so please have patience :).

I imported multiple data.frames using the code:

```
setwd("C:/movie1")
data_list <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")

for (i in 1:length(data_list1)) 
assign(data_list1[i], 
     read.csv(data_list1[i],  
                  sep= ",", 
                  dec = ".",
                  header = T))
```

which resulted in data.frames named: "well_0.csv", "well_1.csv", etc.
(I found this peace of code here, so thank you)

Since I want to import another set of data.frames from a different directory, but with identical names and merge them I would like to change the names of these data.frames to something like "well_0_movie1" or at least "well_0.csv_movie1" so R doesn't overwrite them. 
Please help

Comment: Do you need to use `assign`? Why not just read the data.frames into a list using lapply?

Comment: Do yourself a big favor [and use a list of data frames instead of a bunch of sequentially named data frames](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061).

Comment: @Gregor I was thiking about this but I would have to rewrite my entire code and I don't know if I currently have the time or skill to do this, but tnx for the link. Do you say this because it speeds up the execution (that's what I read) or makes handling data easier?

Comment: @Dason no special reason for using `assign` (that's the answer i found here). Working hard last couple of days to figure out these functions. I'm actually rewriting my code from loading one file at a time to something a bit more elegant so `assign` seemed like an improvement :P

Comment: It won't necessarily speed up execution, but it makes your code easier to write and less likely to have bugs. For example, the entire code in your question would be simplified to `setwd("C:/movie1"); data_list = lapply(list.files(pattern = "*.csv"), read.csv, sep = ",", dec = ".", header = T)`. And instead of messing more with `assign` if you want to change the names, you would just use `names()` which you are probably already familiar with.

Comment: But the real benefits are downstream. If you wanted to, say, check the dimension of each of your data frames you can do `sapply(dat_list, dim)` instead of writing a for loop to go over the names of your objects, using `get` to get the actual object and then using `dim` on it, and assigning the result to a preallocated matrix or list.

Comment: @Gregor hmm thank you for the advice. I will try to do this, but data types in R still confuse me sometimes so I'm not sure what functions I can and cannot use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `.csv` from the first time you load your data by using `gsub` and subsequently use `paste` add `_movie1`:

```
data_list1 <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in data_list1) 
  assign(gsub(".csv","",i),
         read.csv(i,header=T))


#Second time (in a different directory)
data_list2 <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (j in data_list2) 
  assign(paste(gsub(".csv","",j),"movie1",sep = "_"),
         read.csv(j,header=T, sep = ",", dec = "."))
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
assign(sprintf("%s_movie1",data_list1[i]), read.csv(data_list1[i], sep= ",", dec = ".", header = T))
```

I can not test it right now, I hope not to have a typographic error.